# Android Bluetooth Devices donot Show up in listbox

Tags: android, bluetooth

My application works fine..But it does not show up bluetooth devices in listbox...i have checked them by applying toast..all devices do show on toast but not on listbox..please help..i am writing here code and layout file..thanks

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.bluetoothcheck5;
import java.util.Set;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    protected ArrayAdapter<String> mArrayAdapter;
    protected BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter =    BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

final Button buttonSearch = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSearch);
  mArrayAdapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);



 buttonSearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ListView listViewPairedDevices = (ListView)   findViewById(R.id.listview1);
        //BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter =    BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        Set<BluetoothDevice> mPairedDevices =   mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
        if (mPairedDevices.size() > 0) 
        {
            for (BluetoothDevice mDevice : mPairedDevices) 
            {
                Log.v("Title", "PairedDevices: " + mDevice.getName() + " " +   mDevice.getAddress());
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), mDevice.getName(),   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), mDevice.getAddress(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                listViewPairedDevices.setAdapter(mArrayAdapter);

            }
        }



     }

});}}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView android:text="" android:id="@+id/out" android:layout_width="wrap_content"      android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="TURN_ON" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="19dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1"
    android:text="DISCOVERABLE" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
    android:text="TURN_OFF" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonSearch"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
    android:text="Search Devices" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button3" >
</ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pass the list you want to display for ArrayAdapter method

```
mArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myList);
listViewPairedDevices.setAdapter(mArrayAdapter );
```

Where myList is an list of items you want to display in listview